# Netty binding to wrong interface

Tags: java, networking, netty

I set up a loopback adapter on my Win7 PC so that I could bind to it with Netty. The thing is I assigned the Loopback address an IP address of `172.16.1.1 /24` (which is required). But when I try to bind through Netty it instead binds to the `127.0.0.1` address - known as the default localhost IP. So I'm just wondering how I can work around this? I need it SPECIFICALLY to bind to the Loopback adapter with IP address `172.16.1.1` and port `162`.

Pictures related: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn6qm.png

```
NetUtil  - Loopback interface: Software Loopback Interface 1
NetUtil  - Loopback address: /127.0.0.1 (primary) <--- the problem
NetUtil  - Loopback address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Code related:

```
public class SnmpServer {

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SnmpServer");
//private final static String SNMP_HOST_IP = "172.16.1.1";
private static final byte[] SNMP_HOST_ADDR = {(byte)172, (byte)16, (byte)1, (byte)1};
private final static int SNMP_TRAP_PORT = 162;

final ServerBootstrap snmpBootstrap;

public SnmpServer() {
    snmpBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
}

public void bind() throws Exception {
    final EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    final EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    final SocketAddress socket =
            new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(SNMP_HOST_ADDR), SNMP_TRAP_PORT);
    try {
        snmpBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new SnmpChannelHandler());

        final ChannelFuture future = snmpBootstrap.bind(socket).sync();
        //future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The thing is that 127.0.0.1 *is* the loopback address, and 172.16.1.1 isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was that Netty was binding to all the addresses located in my HOSTS file. I simply navigated to that file and added the address for `172.16.1.1    localhost` in there and then called `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")`.

Answer (score 0):

The NetUtil output has nothing todo to which it binds. It will bind to the InetSocketAddress you pass to the bind(...) method.