# Connecting to an Android server with websocket

Tags: android, networking, netty, mqtt

I am running an MQTT Broker/Server (it's a modified version of [moquette](https://github.com/andsel/moquette)) on an Android phone (Motorola Moto 3g, Android 6.0) which accept request through standard connection on the port 1883 and websocket connection through port 9001.

When I am trying to connect to the server on the same phone that the server is running on with a MQTT websocket client everything works (with host 127.0.0.1 and port 9001).

But, if I am trying to connect to the server with my laptop connected to the **same local network** it fails. Same thing if I create a hotspot WiFi on my laptop and connect to it with the phone.

A quick NMap scan seems to reveal that the 9001 port on the phone is closed :

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-23 12:20 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.100.100.134
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9001/tcp closed tor-orport

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

So my guess is either the server is listening on the wrong interface (I found this `DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil  - Loopback interface: lo (lo, ::1%1)` in the adb log, but it doesn't seem to be the problem, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21661387/1149206)) or that I need to open the port manually on the phone but I didn't found anything about that on Google.

Comment: what `host` value do you have in your mosquette config file?

Comment: I use in memory config file using the Properties class, and the properties are :
`prop.setProperty("port", "1883");
  prop.setProperty("websocket_port", "9001");
  prop.setProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");
  prop.setProperty("allow_anonymous", "true");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are forcing the broker to only listen on the loopback interface:

```
prop.setProperty("port", "1883"); 
prop.setProperty("websocket_port", "9001"); 
prop.setProperty("host", "127.0.0.1"); 
prop.setProperty("allow_anonymous", "true");
```

You need to change it to the following:

```
prop.setProperty("port", "1883"); 
prop.setProperty("websocket_port", "9001"); 
prop.setProperty("host", "0.0.0.0"); 
prop.setProperty("allow_anonymous", "true");
```

`0.0.0.0` represents all interfaces where as `127.0.0.1` is only the loopback